# Smooth transition of .addclass as well as setting scrollTop to a specific div?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have achieved my desired effect of changing the background color of my navbar on scroll, with this jquery code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
        navbar = $('.acetrnt-stickynav-transparent');

    if (scrollPos > 800) {
  navbar.addClass('acetrnt-stickynav-color');
    } else {
  navbar.removeClass('acetrnt-stickynav-color');
    }
  });
});
```

But there is one things I can't figure out.  I want:

a: is it possible to have the .addclass initiat only after reaching a certain div, in my case, my container div?

You can view my live site here.  http://www.acetronaut.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the smooth transition, add `transition: background-color .3s ease;` to `.acetrnt-stickynav-transparent` and change the time and easing function to match your taste.

To trigger the transition at the `#container` div instead of the arbitrary 800px mark, replace 800 with `$('#container').offset().top` in your code.

Comment: Hi!  Yeah, I just figured the transition part out, and edited my post.

Comment: Nvm, I had some padding at the top of container.  It does work!  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I have it so my banner scrolls to container, and I want the nav bar to change to black at that point.  It appears that your fix requires me to scroll 1 more pixel manually for it to activate.

Comment: you can put  `$('#container').offset().top - 1` to get it to kick in 1px sooner

Comment: Thanks!  I am still learning jQuery so all of these variables are beyond me.  You are a life saver.  :)